# Update config file after value change

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration

I am updating one setting in my config file on button click. The code i found is easy to understand and I am sure it works that way. But the problem lies with either updating the section in my config file or writing to it.

So on button click it goes through this method:

```
private static void UpdateSetting(string key, string value)
{
    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
    configuration.Save();

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("applicationSettings");
}
```

And this is the targetet section in my config file:

```
 <applicationSettings>
  <UpdatePackager.Properties.Settings>
   <setting name="Sourcepath" serializeAs="String">
    <value>D:\PMSmart</value>
   </setting>
   <setting name="DestinationpathUpdatePackages" serializeAs="String">
    <value>D:\xxx</value>
   </setting>
   <setting name="DestinationpathClient" serializeAs="String">
    <value>D:\xxx</value>
   </setting>
   <setting name="Versions" serializeAs="String">
    <value>v5_9_0/v5_9_1/v5_9_2</value>
   </setting>
  </UpdatePackager.Properties.Settings>
 </applicationSettings>
```

Am i missing something or doing something the wrong way?

Comment: *" still no updating targetet value"* - how do you determine that? Is the setting displayed somewhere and it's not updated or how?

Comment: i have the settings written in the config file, in which i can go check if something has changed. and after closing and reopneing the application nothing has changed as well.

Comment: configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);  And I hope you are opening the right section name and refreshes the same

Comment: I will try this. And yes it is the right section name.

Answer (score 2):

It is the `.config` file in the output directory of your `.exe` that should get updated, and not the one in your project folder.

When you build the application and run it again, the modified config file will be overwritten by the one in your project folder.

Check the value in the `.config` file in the `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release` folder during runtime and you should see that it has been updated after your `UpdateSetting` method has been executed.

Comment: Jeah i also came to this conclusion after some search and a tip from a coworker. But sadly i dont know how to update the right file. Could find no code after a google search and I'm very new to c#

Comment: The "right" file is the file in the output directory. Your application shouldn't modify your source files...